# How can I create block for my custom form?

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I create a custom form module. Now I want show my form in a block. How can I do this ?

Note: I create MymoduleBlock.php in /modules/my-module/src/Plugin/Block path with this code but not work:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my-module\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

class MymoduleBlock extends BlockBase {
  public function build() {
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\my-module\Form\MymoduleForm');
    return $form;
   }
}
```

Comment: If that is indeed all your code then you are missing the annotation. Check the docblock of other blocks. the @Block part is required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in `MymoduleBlock::build()` is correct, and it is what Drupal core does in [`UserLoginBlock::build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21UserLoginBlock.php/function/UserLoginBlock%3A%3Abuild/8.4.x).

```
  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm');
  unset($form['name']['#attributes']['autofocus']);
  // When unsetting field descriptions, also unset aria-describedby attributes
  // to avoid introducing an accessibility bug.
  // @todo Do this automatically in https://www.drupal.org/node/2547063.
  unset($form['name']['#description']);
  unset($form['name']['#attributes']['aria-describedby']);
  unset($form['pass']['#description']);
  unset($form['pass']['#attributes']['aria-describedby']);
  $form['name']['#size'] = 15;
  $form['pass']['#size'] = 15;
```

What the block definition is missing is the annotation (the comment before the class) which allows Drupal to identify that class as plugin. See what [Block API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/group/block_api/8.4.x) says. (Emphasis is mine.)

> Blocks are a combination of a configuration entity and a **plugin**. The configuration entity stores placement information (theme, region, weight) and any other configuration that is specific to the block. The **block plugin** does the work of rendering the block's content for display.
>
> Block plugins use **the annotations** defined by [`\Drupal\Core\Block\Annotation\Block`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21Annotation%21Block.php/class/Block/8.4.x). See the [Annotations topic](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/annotation/8.4.x) for more information about annotations.

In the block class I used as example, the annotation is the following one.

```
/*
 * @Block(
 *   id = "user_login_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("User login"),
 *   category = @Translation("Forms")
 * )
 */
```

Also, the machine name of module should not contain hyphens, which aren't allowed in PHP functions. That creates problems when you implement hooks, since the hook name is derived from the machine name of the module. For example, the implementation of [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.4.x) for your module would be `my-module_page_attachments()`, which is not an acceptable PHP function name.
If you think your module is not going to implement hooks, keep in mind that the majority of modules implements at least [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.4.x), for which is also preferable not using capital letters in the module machine name.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you are posting all your code you are missing annotations in your Block class. Annotations are used by Drupal 8 to register plugins.

Check out this link to get started on custom blocks:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-block

Don't forget to clear your cache after creating your block plugin.

P.S. I see that you named your module 'my-module'. Dashes are not allowed in module names, use underscores. For more information about module naming please see: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/naming-and-placing-your-drupal-8-module