# How can I return HTML form in BlockBase build function?

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I include some form from API. And I want to include it in block, using `Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase`. My function return HTML tags, that has tag `<form>`.

But function `build()` return empty array.

```
$element = array(
  '#markup' => $html
);
return $element;
```

Comment: Don’t return straight html, return the form array itself

Comment: [How can I create block for my custom form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/242730/15055)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create block for my custom form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/242730/how-can-i-create-block-for-my-custom-form)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to include your tags in the `#allowed_tags`, because this markup is filtered in [Xss::filterAdmin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/function/Xss%3A%3AfilterAdmin).

```
$element = [
  '#markup' => $html,
  '#allowed_tags' => ['form', 'input', ...]
];
return $element;
```